# Can Hibernate Validator 3.x coexist with 4.x?

Tags: classpath, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, jboss-4.2.x

Can Hibernate Validator version 3.x (proprietary) coexist with version 4.x (JSR-303 compliant) in the same application server lib? I'm using JBoss 4.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think this should work. I had a short look at the legacy sources and couldn't find any colliding classes, so you might just give it a try.